# Drupal: Change label for a default Node Module Form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hook, drupal-hooks, input-field

I’ve a specific content where a user can add a new post to it by using a form. This form is used all over the site for different kind of content but in this specific form, I need to edit the first input form, the “title”. It is the input-form name I need to edit so instead it is called “title” I need it to say: “job title”.

When I’m looking at the admin function where I can edit my form and fields (Manage fields), the label for this is called “job title” and but its name is **“Node Module Form”** and has no type or setting link attached to it.
And eventhough the label is called “job title” it is somehow overridden and still called “title” when I’m going to enter a new content in that content-type.

I simply cannot figure out where this override is happening and how I can edit this specific name (label) for this input-form.

I would like this input-form to be present because it shows up in the right areas of the site (both as URL and headline for the posted content, etc.) but with the new label for this input-field.

Does anyone know how or where I can change this for this specific content-type?
I’ve been contemplating about **hooks** is the right way to do this but I’m not that experienced with the **hook** functionality.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: Post your solution here, so that it might help somebody who may come looking here for the solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the content type (The main settings, not "Manage fields" "Display fields" or "Template"
2. Expand the collapsed area titled "Submission From Settings"

Here; you can change the "Title Field Label"